# Is there a way to listen for changes in json coming via an API from server?

Tags: android, json, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm making a cricket live score android application. I bought an API for that and started working on my app. The API response is in JSON. I am able to send the request to the server and get data in JSON. I am also able to show that data in my app but the thing is, in cricket, data can change at any time. There's no fixed time for changes in data so I want to listen for changes in data. I tried it by myself but failed. So, I basically wrote code to fetch data every 10 seconds. Now I'm able to fetch and show fresh data but still, there's a problem. Since I'm fetching data every 10 seconds, my app is consuming a lot of memory and because of that, my app crashes after a point of time. Mostly when the heap reaches somewhere around 180 MB.

Can you please help to find out an efficient way of refreshing data of my android app because I believe using this much memory is not a good idea.

Comment: Definitely take a look at using WebSockets. Also your heap should not be taking that much memory. Can you post some code?

Comment: You might want to try Firebase too.

Comment: How can i use firebase to pass my JSON data? That JSON is coming from a different server. @Enzokie

Comment: If you can't modify the server code I am afraid this is not possible. You can use Firebase in your server to signal all the connected devices that a change is occurring, in that moment you know you should do a server fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rb612 because he told me to try WebSocket. Using WebSocket, I can't listen for changes but I can refresh data every 1000 milliseconds which makes my data almost real-time sync. I just did a few other things like storing variable locally as much as possible.